# Setting window title to page title

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently trying to display the current page title as window title. my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Your_choice_1.MainWindow" 
        namespace:"Your_choice_1" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="{Binding Path=Content.Title, ElementName=_mainFrame}" 
        Height="450" Width="800" 
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" Source="Index.xaml" Margin="0,-8,0,8" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm aware some bits are left out because for some reason the editor wouldn't let me post it otherwise - but the important thing is the title binding anyway. Is this the wrong way to go about it? As title I get the project name and index.xaml, not the page title itself.

EDIT: 
What I'm trying to achieve is that the window title (title of MainWindow.xaml) updates whenever a new page gets displayed in the frame. The window title should be the same as the page title.
[In this article](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation)
the solution I'm currently using got presented, but it's not working as expected, displaying Projectname/URI-to-page rather than the page title as the window title.
Example:
Window title should be "your choice - the Mission" (as it is the page title) - in fact the window title is your_choice_1;compontent/Index.xaml

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If I wrote title="Words", the window title would be set to Words, regardless of the page title.

Comment: Sorry, should have made more clear-- Why not just make `Title=` the same text as the window you are needing? Or are you wanting it to change with every window?

Comment: Because I'm creating a navigator app: Which window gets displayed in the frame changes while the program runs, thus the window title should change according to page displayed.

Comment: Please clarify your question within the post, then. :) What are you needing? What isn't working and why? Right now, the only question within the post is `Is this the wrong way to go about it?` Rather than explaining what the issue is along _with_ the question. :)

Comment: Thought I said what I wanted to achieve above the code, but OK, I'll try to clarify... A sec. (updating post...)

Comment: Correct, you stated what your end goal is, not what your question is or what is wrong with what you have :)

Comment: Post updated. Tried to be a bit more elaborate...

Answer (score 0):

This Code is working fine for me: (I don't see an error in your Code...???)

Is your index.xaml of type Page or having a Title property?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="{Binding Path=Content.Title, ElementName=MainFrame}" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Source="Index.xaml">

        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Index.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApp1.Index"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Index Tester">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hallo"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Ohhh... I just realized... The window title is set correctly, however, much like I'd see a URL in a browser, I'm seeing the URI of the frame (and kept mistaking this as window title.) Sorry, this was a combination of me using a screenreader and not being familiar with WPF xD